# Column name as variable in select

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to acheive the functionality like this how can i do this.

```
DECLARE @filterByDate VARCHAR(20)

IF(@filterByDate = 'expectedDate')
   SET @filterByDate = 'ExpectedStartDate'
ELSE
   SET @filterByDate = 'ActualStartDate'

SELECT @filterByDate AS Date
FROM TableName
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @filterByDate VARCHAR(20)

 IF(@filterByDate = 'expectedDate')
    SET @filterByDate = 'ExpectedStartDate'
 ELSE
    SET @filterByDate = 'ActualStartDate'

 Declare @Sql varchar(max)

 SET @SQL = 'SELECT @Filter AS DATE FROM TableName'
 DECLARE @ParmDefinition nVARCHAR(20)
 SET @ParmDefinition = N'@filter nvarchar(20)'
 exec sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @Filter = @filterByDate
```

Comment: thanks this was helpful **DECLARE @filterByDate VARCHAR(20)
SET @filterByDate = 'ExpectedStartDate'

 Declare @Sql varchar(max)

 SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @filterByDate + ' AS DATE, insertDate FROM Worksheet'
 EXEC(@SQL)**

Comment: IF @filterByDate isn't sanitised, you have a SQL injection risk

Comment: No injection here - only parameter passed into sp_executesql is declared and set inside the usp. No benefit to passing in as parameter either.

Comment: but yes - if this wasn't within a usp then I'd agree

Comment: I have to pass @filterByDate as a parameter in the stored procedure. i think for stored procedure there is no risk of sql injection. am i right?

Comment: @Sami: if the parameter @filterByDate is '1,DELETE Users;-' then it isn't safe

Answer (score 4):

SQL Standard, works on most RDBMS

```
SELECT CASE @filterByDate
         WHEN 'ExpectedStartDate' THEN ExpectedStartDate
         WHEN 'ActualStartDate' THEN ActualStartDate
         ELSE NULL
       END as mydate
       --optional , @filterByDate AS ColumnName
FROM
   MyTable
```