# Using a variable/function as a dynamic column name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use a function or a variable as the label for a column in MySQL?

So for example if you wanted to include the date, something like:

```
select 
  sum(P.AMOUNT) AS monthname(date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
from
  PAYMENT P
WHERE
  P.CREATED_DATE > (date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

This fails, as it's not the correct syntax for an AS alias. I've also tried this:

```
SET @s = monthname(date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));

select 
  sum(P.AMOUNT) AS @s
from
  PAYMENT P
WHERE
  P.CREATED_DATE > (date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Which also doesn't work...

Any ideas?

EDIT - With the above example i realize you could actually just use an additional column to return the date info. The problem is i have a few columns with various date ranges, like this:

```
select
  sum(IF((P.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH)),P.amount,0)) AS 'Month 0',
  sum(IF((P.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),P.amount,0)) AS 'Month -1',
  sum(IF((P.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)),P.amount,0)) AS 'Month -2'
from
  PAYMENT P
WHERE
  P.AMOUNT < 100000;
```

So it's the "Month 0" etc i'm looking to replace with a function/query.

Comment: It's the wrong approach: Instead, just return the month name as a column and use it in your app layer

Comment: The problem is i'm using different date ranges in different columns using if's so i can't put the date in a row as a single row has multiple date ranges. I'll update the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column name as variable in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424582/column-name-as-variable-in-select)